# How to restrict an AWS-IoT Thing to Publish/Subscribe to some topics in AWS IoT-Core?

Tags: aws-iot

I am creating a AWS-IoT thing dynamically that can publish any topic and can listen to any topic in the AWS-IoT-core broker.

The Policy I am using is very broad and this thing can perform all operations in the server:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to narrow these options. I want to allow this thing just to publish to the topics `TOPICS-TEST/#` and subscribe ONLY to the topics `TOPICS-TEST/#`. Even though we have many different topics in the broker I want this thing to only have access to the topics that starts with `TOPICS-TEST/`.

In order to do that I was checking [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html) and I have created this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Connect"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxx:client/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Subscribe"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxx:topicfilter/TOPICS-TEST/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Receive"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxx:topicfilter/TOPICS-TEST/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Publish"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxx:topicfilter/TOPICS-TEST/*"
            ]
    }
    ]
}
```

The previous policy is not working.
I can't see nothing, I can't publishing nothing.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the way to do that

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:topicfilter/TOPICS-TEST*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:topic/TOPICS-TEST/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The previous policy will allow the thing to receive notifications from AWS-IoT core, to connect, to push ONLY to the sub-topics `TOPICS-TEST/ ...` and subscribe to `TOPICS-TEST/...`. This wing will not be able to see other topics in this broker.

I was using `...:topicfilter/...` for Publish. Should be `...:topic/...`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the solution, but what if you have millions of things and have different topics for different shadows.
Do we got to attach all devices to this policy.

In my opinion I feel there should be some IAM policy which should be applicable in this case. I find this tutorial project very useful.

https://youtu.be/1Pk05kpBX2A